# Best method for connecting user applications (which relly on SQL) over VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, windows-server, remoteapp

Two questions here:

1.  I'm trying to get some end user applications in a functional state at a remote office.  We have a decent site-to-site VPN and most programs work without issue (file explorer for shared drives, etc).  But we have a couple of applications which rely on an SQL connection to a server at the main site and they are incredibly slow over the VPN.  I've been exploring RDS as a solution to this, whether that's through Remote Desktop or RemoteApps and that definitely solves are speed issue, but it seems very complicated to setup.  Does this seem like a viable solution or am I overlooking something simple?

2.  If RDS is the way to go.  What do I need for licensing?  And what do I need to do in order to make sure that it's setup securely?  They already have Windows Server 2019 with Hyper-V, so I assume I spin up another VM with Server 2019 (and license it) and add the appropriate roles and then get RDS user CALs to install on the RD Licensing host.  But I'm very new to this and could be missing something.

Answer (score 1):

SQL is a database. Lots of Apps are like this (database). Running live over VPN can damage the database, so I suggest not doing this.

Pure Remote Desktop just needs an office computer and (in my experience) no additional licensing requirements.

Better for you, I think, is a Terminal Server and yes, there are licensing requirements for this.

I do recommend for several (numerous) users a properly designed Terminal Server as the best overall approach.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Can you provide some resources about, or expand on, what it takes to have a properly designed Terminal Server?